# Getting DataBinder Item's max value

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I'm working at the `aspx` page, and the following code is inserted in a `Repeater` control:

```
<%# ((System.Collections.Generic.List<double>)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookPrices")).Max() %>
```

Brings up the following error: `'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' does not contain a definition for 'Max'`

List does have an method of `Max()`, so I'm possibly messing up my code somehow. What is my problem?
`BookPrices` is a `list<double>` object, which I'd like to print it's maximum value.

P.S. You guys are great! I didn't find answers for many of my questions on the web. You really are life savers. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure to import `System.Linq`?

`List<T>` does not actually have a `Max` method.  Instead `Max` most often binds to the extension method `Enumerable.Max`.  Linq needs to be imported in order for this to work.

Comment: I'm working at the `aspx` page, I can't import a thing. This code is inserted in a `Repeater` control. BTW I've used list.max few times and i never used `using System.Linq`.

Comment: In the aspx page you do this by <%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>